# Python Webscraping list manipulation

Tags: python, web-scraping

Hey I am new to Python and I am writing a program that extracts data from a webpage. With this search line:

```
carTypeWeb = soup.find_all("span", {"class":"h3"})
```

I get the following output:

```
> [<span class="h3">BMW 420d Gran Coupe M-Sportpaket DIEBSTAHLSCHADEN
> !!</span>,  <span class="h3 u-block">25.950 \u20ac</span>,  <span
> class="h3">BMW 420d Coupe Sport Line,Xenon,Navi,M-Tech,19 Zoll</span>,
> <span class="h3 u-block">26.795 \u20ac</span>,.....]
```

I am now struggling with a) deleting every second item in the list (in the copied example above line 1 and 3) and b) having for lines such as 2 and 4 above only the numerical values (e.g. the price 25950 and 26795) in the list.

Thank you very much for your help in advance; I very much appreciate!

Comment: What does the rest of the surrounding html look like?

Answer (score 0):

If you only want every other line why not changed you code to:

```
carTypeWeb = soup.find_all("span", {"class":"h3 u-block"})
```

Comment: thank you very much. I was able to solve my problem with your help!

Answer (score -1):

You could do something like this:

```
# To read only alternate items of list starting from item 2

for i in range(1, len(carTypeWeb), 2):
    price = (carTypeWeb[i].text).split(' ')[0].replace('.','')
```

In the above code, `.text` extracts the content between `span` tag then `.split[0]`, splits the content at space and 0th part gives you:
`\u25.950`.

After that replacing the `.` in string with no space gives you:
`\u25950`

Then you could just do, `eval(price)` to convert string into integer. I hope that helps.

Comment: thank you very much. I was able to solve my problem with your help!

Comment: If you were able to solve your problem with the above answer then please,  mark it as the answer. Or if you used some part of it then you could also create an answer with your particular solution.